# Twitter BootStrap Responsive CSS in Touch devices

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a few questions about Bootstrap:

1) Implemented our application using bootstrap keeping in view the laptop and Desktop Display.
However now need to be viewed in all touch devices.

2) I've heard Bootstrap supports Responsive CSS supports in all devices(Touch and Non-Touch), however it is not supporting, sometime the layouts appears wierd and doesn't look good.

3) For ex: attaching a sample screen how it appears in normal view and Touch Device    (Iphone 5), observed in Chrome Mobile & Tablet emulator.

Is there any good way, so that it looks feasible and compatible in both Touch and Non-Touch Devices.

Comment: There is no sample attached.  Additionally, bootstrap is in relation to the screen size, regardless of whether it is touch or not.  You need to figure out how you want your site to display in e.g. a phone and a tablet, and then set your css accordingly.  It is not possible to answer this question in the current format.

Comment: You're clearly doing something wrong. Without code to show no one can help you.

Comment: Thanks Paddy and Andrew for quick reply, i'm not authorized to send the images since i don't have enough reputations. I can send the whole code in my view but i think it wont make sense from my end. So will you please help me on what exact info should i send. To test it, you can use FireFox CTRL + SHIFT + M, this worked.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you use bootstrap classes correctly, there will be no broken view on any size screen. To test it, you can use FireFox <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> (don't know combination on chrome, but there is that tool too)